# Join 2 queries by date range and get only first occurrence on join

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

Using SQLite: let's say I have `Calls` table like this:

```
index_call  start_datetime      nextcall_datetime
--------------------------------------------------
1           2024-01-01 08:00AM  2024-01-01 08:24AM
2           2024-01-01 08:24AM  2024-01-01 08:35AM
3           2024-01-01 08:35AM  2024-01-01 08:45AM
```

And an `Event` table as follows:

```
id_event    id_datetime     
------------------------------ 
1           2024-01-01 08:04AM
2           2024-01-01 08:12AM
3           2024-01-01 08:25AM
4           2024-01-01 08:30AM
```

Then I need to get the events that occurred in-between calls, but if there is more than one event, only take the last occurrence.

I tried the following but this produces the cartesian product from both tables.

```
SELECT 
    calls.index_call,
    calls.start_datetime,
    calls.nextcall_datetime,
    event.id_datetime
FROM 
    calls calls 
LEFT JOIN 
    event event 
WHERE 
    events.CreatedDate BETWEEN calls.start_datetime AND calls.nextcall_datetime
```

Expected results:

```
index_call  start_datetime      nextcall_datetime    id_datetime
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1           2024-01-01 08:00AM  2024-01-01 08:24AM   2024-01-01 08:12AM
2           2024-01-01 08:24AM  2024-01-01 08:35AM   2024-01-01 08:30AM
3           2024-01-01 08:35AM  2024-01-01 08:45AM
```

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS and include your desired results for the sample data.

Comment: @Stu I have updated the post including your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Tryit like below:

```sql
SELECT    *
FROM      ( Select      c.INDEX_CALL, START_DATETIME, NEXTCALL_DATETIME, 
                        e.ID_EVENT, ID_DATETIME,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By c.INDEX_CALL Order By e.ID_DATETIME Desc) "RN_ORDER"
            From        calls c
            Left Join   event e  ON(e.ID_DATETIME >= c.START_DATETIME And e.ID_DATETIME < c.NEXTCALL_DATETIME)
          )
WHERE     RN_ORDER = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can even use the `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
SELECT calls.index_call,
       calls.start_datetime,
       calls.nextcall_datetime,
       event.id_datetime
  FROM calls
  LEFT JOIN event ON event.CreatedDate >= calls.start_datetime 
                 AND event.CreatedDate < calls.nextcall_datetime
WHERE event.id_event is null 
   or not exists 
      (SELECT 1 FROM event t  
       WHERE t.CreatedDate < event.CreatedDate
       AND t.CreatedDate >= calls.start_datetime 
       AND t.CreatedDate < calls.nextcall_datetime)
```